# Laravel 4 redirect logged in users to a specific page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hello what I am trying to do is fairly simple I know it can be done with routes.php I am confused about how to do it, I would like all logged in users to not be able to see "/"
so when they try to access '/' they get send to '/name'

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    // ...
    return Redirect::to('/name');
});
```

this doesnt check if they are logged in

Answer (score 0):

Use before filters:

```
Route::get('/', function() {

    return View::make('your-home-view-comes-here');

})->before('auth');
```

Edit the `filters.php` file and change it to:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('/name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd also might want to group the routes to a filter as explained in

[laravel's route groups](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups)

this will be easier to manage if you want that filter to run for multiple route item.